# How to redirect from browser, back to the mobile app that opened it?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-router

Im working on a website, which is opened by a mobile app, externally, in the phone's browser. (Not React WebView)

I want to implement a "back" button in the browser, which redirects the user back to the mobile app when pressed.

The details of the mobile app is unknown, other than knowing that they open an external browser view.

Is there a way to redirect the user back to the mobile app, that opened the browser in the first place? Preferably without needing to configure the mobile app.
Our website uses React.

Comment: Wouldn't enough "back navigation" actions eventually close the webview and go back to the app? Or just closing the webview? In the webview is there not a "close back to app" type button? How is the website being opened from the native device?

Comment: @DrewReese

There is actually a "close back to app" button. This button already does what is required, but is too small on IOS, which could cause problems for old people, bad vision, etc.

We need a big button in the web view, which essentially does that exact thing.

Im not sure how the mobile app's link to our website, only that they open our website in a new window, using the phones default-browser.

Enough "back navigation" will probably return the user to the mobile app. Is it possible to find this exact number somehow so it can be done in a single button press?

Comment: "Is it possible to find this exact number somehow so it can be done in a single button press" I suppose this depends on how much navigation the user does in the webapp. If they don't navigate, then a single back navigation should close the webview and direct them back to the app, they they click a few links (*forward navigation actions*), then a few back navigations would be necessary.

Comment: You generally shouldn't be too concerned with 3rd-party plugin accessibility. If they are accessible, then they should work with settings the user has set for their needs, i.e. any screen scaling, font size, etc. If this isn't the case then it may be an issue to raise with the team that developed the native app and is using a plugin or similar to open the webview, there may be accessibility settings they can select since this is all at the native level.

Comment: One possible solution is to use a unique URI action (using your website url) and in case of android app you can register a receiver allowing you to consume said URI.